# Create a Non Empty and Shared Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I would like confirmation of the approach I want to take since I have not worked with these API's before

I am trying to create an IOS app that when you click the create button it will create a Google Spreadsheet for you on your Google drive with the following properties

1) The spreadsheet will have some cells filled in and formatted.
[image]

2) The spreadsheet will be shared with a specific email address.

Is this possible to do ?

I was thinking of using the Files: copy function on the GoogleDrive Api, and the Permissions: update, is this the correct direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes thats correct except its permissions insert. Another way is to create a new one and use cell feed to write the header, but its more code and you wont be able to do the formatting.
When making a copy specify a name too otherwise it will be 'copy of x'

Comment: Thanks for you answer, What is the issue with the permissions, Do you know how I could do it ?